# Preventing lazy-loading gives me 1 "subentity"

Tags: doctrine-orm, lazy-loading, symfony-2.1

I have a problem with Doctrine (Symfony2.1). I want to prevent lazy-loading by join fetching subentities (OneToMany relation) but I got only one result for those subentities.

For example:

```
public function getSingleProjectQuery($project){
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->select(array("p", "fb"))
            ->where('p.id = :project_id')->setParameter('project_id', $project)
            ->leftJoin('p.feedbacks', 'fb')
            ->groupBy('p.id')
            ->getQuery();
    return $query;
}
```

In this example Doctrine returns me the "Project"-object and one single "feedback" object (but there are more than one feedbacks...).
When I replace the select to this: `->select(array("p"))`
I got all the "Feedback" objects but there are then lazy-loaded (many queries).

see http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#joins

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `groupBy` clause.